# Applying OnFocusChangeListener and OnItemSelectedListener to Spinner

Tags: android, listener, android-spinner

I have a spinner that works fine with the standard OnItemSelectedListener to present a set of options:

```
s.setAdapter(adapter);
s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int selectedPosition, long arg3) {

        if (selectedPosition == 0) {
            // do stuff
        } else {
            // other stuff
        }
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    }
});
```

However, I have a new requirement that when the user clicks on the Spinner to use it, a corresponding Button is disabled. I have added the following OnFocusChangeListener to the Spinner:

```
s.setFocusable(true);
s.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
s.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            distanceButton.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            distanceButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }

});
```

This works, and disables the button. HOWEVER, the spinner now need TWO clicks to bring up the options, when without the OnFocusChangeListener it needed only one click. Is there any way to combine both operations into one Listener?

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to call super.onFocusChange(v, hasFocus) after your if-clause.

```
 public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            distanceButton.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            distanceButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
        super.onFocusChange(v, hasFocus);
    }
```